# React Native setting.gradle solved

Tags: reactjs, react-native, error-handling, compilation

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 stopped Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/home/dharmendra/Documents/gitlab/rnative/AwesomeProject/android/settings.gradle' (/home/dharmendra/.gradle/caches/7.5.1/scripts/6hrksilieebwgbc2tk6l5h8hd).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 30s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/home/dharmendra/Documents/gitlab/rnative/AwesomeProject/android/settings.gradle' (/home/dharmendra/.gradle/caches/7.5.1/scripts/6hrksilieebwgbc2tk6l5h8hd).
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem final only change JAVA Version 18 Use in java of version

1. Check java -version :- if showing 19.x.x then change java version 18.x.x install.
   follow the step :
2. sudo apt update
3. sudo apt install -y openjdk-18-jdk
4. sudo apt install -y openjdk-18-jre

then run your project
npx react-native start && npx react-native run-android
.............................